# Generating set for a polynomial ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I would like to know which is the generator set for the following polynomial ideal:
$$
I=\{a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\,\, | \,\, a_0\,\, \text{is even}\}.
$$

Sorry for the writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any polynomial of the form $f(x) = \sum_0^{\deg f} f_i x^i \in \Bbb Z [x]$ with $f_0$ even may be written as $f(x) = x p(x) + 2n$ where $p(x) = \sum_1^{\deg f} f_i x^{i - 1}$ and $f_i, n \in \Bbb Z$; here $f_0 = 2n$.  This shows that $f(x) \in \langle 2, x \rangle$; also, it is clear that $f(x) \in \langle 2, x \rangle$ may be expressed in the form $2q(x) + xp(x)$ for some $p(x), q(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$; with $q(x) = \sum_0^{\deg q} q_i x^i$ and $p(x) = \sum_0^{\deg p} p_i x^i$ we have $f_0 = 2q_0$ and $f_i = 2q_i + p_{i - 1}$ for $i \ge 1$; thus $f(x) = 2q_0 + x\sum_1^{\deg f} (2q_i + p_{i - 1})x^{i - 1}$ has an even constant term.  Thus the set of all polynomials $f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ with $f_0$ even is precisely $\langle 2, x \rangle$; the generators are $2$ and $x$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You know that $x\in I$.  What does $x$ generate?  Is there anything to add to get the rest?